# How to use min in dataframe

Tags: r

How to print the day having minimum wind and the day having maximum temperature from dataset `airquality`? I tried:

```
data(airquality)
min(airquality$Wind)
```

but it just gives me the value 1.7.

**Edit:**

OK, now I know `which.min`. I tried:

```
airquality[which.min(airquality$Wind),]
#Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
#53    NA      59  1.7   76     6  22
```

But I want to print just the two last column Month and Day.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```r
airquality[airquality$Wind == min(airquality$Wind), ]
```

I think this is more general than `which.min` because `which.min` cannot deal with ties.

Comment: #thank you.                                                                                                                                     how to print the day and month like this                                                                                   Month Day
  6         22

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution:

```
airquality[,5:6][which.min(airquality$Wind), ]
#   Month Day
#53     6  22
```

I just find it by trying. Thank you for your help.

---

Or as Zheyuan Li suggested:

```
airquality[which.min(airquality$Wind), c("Month", "Day")]
airquality[which.min(airquality$Wind), 5:6]

airquality[which.max(airquality$Wind), c("Month", "Day")]
airquality[which.max(airquality$Wind), 5:6]

airquality[c(which.min(airquality$Wind), which.max(airquality$Wind)), c("Month", "Day")]
airquality[c(which.min(airquality$Wind), which.max(airquality$Wind)), 5:6]
```

Comment: #Hi Li please I have a question                                                                                               Generate four random integers between 1 and 100. By checking the remainder
of each of four numbers by two, print one of the following:
There are four odd numbers.
 There are three odd numbers and one even number.
There are two odd numbers and two even numbers.
There are one odd number and three even numbers.
There are four even numbers.        can we do it without using : >- for()

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `subset`:

```r
data(airquality)
output <- subset(airquality, Wind == min(Wind))
output[,5:6]
#>    Month Day
#> 53     6  22
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you !! we can do this too                                                                                               > subset(airquality,Wind==min(Wind),select = c(Month,Day))
   Month Day
53     6  22